# How can I inject from a field?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I use Spring and I can inject from a method.

```
@Bean
ILogger loggerService() {
    return new ILogger() {
        public void log() {
            System.out.println("Logger!");              
        }               
    };
}
```

But I'd like to inject from a field:

```
@ ??? annotation
ILogger logger = new ILogger(){
    public void log() {
        System.out.println("Logger!");
    }   
};
```

Can it be possible? Which annotation should I use?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. In Spring JavaConfig all beans in the @Configuration must be produced by methods of the class